# JSONP Internet Explorer no callback

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, callback, jsonp

All browsers except for Internet Explorer properly call the javascript and add them to the page.

I see a lot of posts on JSONP problems in IE, but I haven't come across one in this form. Why is the function issuesToList not called?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="RedmineJSONP.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>List of Issues</h1>
    </header>

    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="http://www.redmine.org/issues.json?callback=issuesToList"></script>

</body>

</html>


function issuesToList(data) {
    var count = data.issues.length;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var issue = data.issues[i];
        loadIssue(issue);
    }
}

//Create an issue instance and append to Ui
function loadIssue(issue){    
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = "+";
    button.setAttribute("onClick", "toggleInfo(this)");

    var p = document.createElement("p");

    var item = document.createElement("div");       
    item.setAttribute("id", issue.id);
    item.setAttribute("class", "issue");
    item.appendChild(button);
    item.innerHTML += " " + issue.subject;
    item.appendChild(p);

    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    container.appendChild(item);        
}
```

EDIT Removed the double http://

Comment: Your URL `http://http://www.redmine.org/issues.json?limit=10&callback=issuesToList` is invalid, and if I fix it, I get JSON, not JSONP, so I don't understand how it would work in any browser.

Comment: I entered another URL when I uploaded my post here, so I wouldn't have to write down my own password and username. So in which browser did you test it?

Comment: Try providing a test case that demonstrates the problem. This one has a clear problem (the URL points to JSON not JSONP) which you say isn't in the actual code.

Comment: Are you even sure the problem is with the JSONP? Have you tried creating a test case with hardcoded data? Try creating a minimal test case: http://sscce.org/

Comment: It return JSON, the technique is JSONP (with padding). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: Like I said I tested my stuff on chrome safari firefox. they all worked, except for internet explorer

Comment: "It return JSON, the technique is JSONP (with padding)" — The data at the URL you give doesn't have the padding, that's my point.

Comment: "Like I said I tested my stuff on chrome safari firefox. they all worked, except for internet explorer" — Yes, you've established that. You haven't established where the problem lies (not clearly anyway - you say that issuesToList isn't called but you haven't said how you've proven that). I suspect that it is being called and that the problem would be with the DOM manipulation (IE has, historically, been weird about that). Try narrowing down where the problem is. The first thing you could do would be to get rid of the JSONP and just hard code some data into the script.

Comment: I checked again and looked in the console for the problem. When I use redmine.org I get this error.

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : 


When I use my own redmine it works in chrome. I would not know what else to hardcode in <script src=""></script> that calls a function in RedmineJSONP.js

Comment: "Unexpected token :" — Yes, that's what happens when you try to treat JSON as JSONP.  "I would not know what else to hardcode in `<script src=""></script>`" — As I said, hardcode the data into a single script, don't use JSONP, see if you can still reproduce the problem.